# Transaction Effective Gas Price

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, gas-price, golang

I am developing in Go and I have a question that I have been looking for the solution for a long time and I am not able to find it.

How can I find the effective gas price used in the transaction? Not the one that I have indicated to execute it, but the one that has been finally used. When I ask for the gas price of the transaction I can get the Base Fee or the Max Fee, but not the real price.

[image: Tx Information]

Thanks in advance,

A.

Added: The Transaction is `0x4114edac2eee32ac222bbe834bf7c6611488332e2072e85781e5a5c71d957e41` in Mainnet

Answer (score 1):

You can get precalculated `effectiveGasPrice` value by calling [eth_getTransactionReceipt](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_gettransactionreceipt) RPC method.

I did not found `EffectiveGasPrice` property anywhere in the `go-ethereum` package though. Instead you can calculate it by yourself by converting transaction into the [Message](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/types/transaction.go#L617). For this you should take [BaseFee](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/types/block.go#L88) value from transaction's block header.

You can get an example from [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/state_processor.go#L77).